# Adobe air application's proxy settings

Tags: air

Is there any way to set application's proxy server setting in adobe air overriding the system settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. AIR 2 has some more native functionality so you might be able to go down into native code and change it but I'm not familiar enough with the native APIs to know if it's possible to change things that way.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Is this still the case with newer versions of Adobe Air? Are there any rules around how Air will pick up the system proxy that people should be aware of?